# How to connect server database using TOAD for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, toad, ora-12170

I use TOAD for Oracle Database  (version 10.6.1.3). And when I try to connect server database it returns error:

> ORA-12170: TNS:Connect time out occurred

I wrote username, password, for DIRECT-Host, Port, SID and connect using: OraClient11g_home. Do u have any idea about this error?

Comment: Can other clients connect? Is there a firewall between you and the server (or on the server)? Have you checked the hostname is right, and resolves to the expected IP address? Can you connect to the server and port using other means, e.g. telnet?

Answer (score 0):

If port 1521 is blocked, you will get this error message.  Make sure the port is open from your source IP (Toad server) to your destination IP (Oracle DB); you can test it with telnet.

Note that it's *possible* to use a different port as well; you can confirm the port configured in Toad in the New Connection window by clicking on the `TNSNames Editor` button.